# wp_query sort with meta_value_num is not working

Tags: wp-query

I have an acf field called totalviews. It stores the total views number for each page i have. The field is number/numeric. Then I am trying to find the page with most views so i sort the number i store in acf field using a wp_query inside functions.php file but i get wrong sort order results. Its messed up not ASC nor DESC ... is my query right? Any help appreciated.

```
$q_args = array(

                'category__not_in' => array( 62,63,170,175,176,171,180 ),
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page'=>'-1',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
                'meta_query' =>array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'picture_url',
                            'value' => 'none',
                            'compare' => '!='
                       ),
                                 array(
                                         'key' => 'totalviews',
                                         'value' => '0',
                                         'compare' => '>=',
                                         'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                                         'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
                                )
    )
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $q_args );
```

Comment: The `orderby` doesn't belong in a `meta_query`. Instead, it's the main args and should be placed after the `meta_query`.

Comment: where exactly???

Comment: `'meta_query' => array( ... ), 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'`

Comment: nope does not work! let me remove the array(
                            'key' => 'picture_url',
                            'value' => 'none',
                            'compare' => '!='
                       ),

Comment: hmmm it worked without the  array(
                            'key' => 'picture_url',
                            'value' => 'none',
                            'compare' => '!='
                       ) but i need to include it in the query... is it possible?

Comment: $q_args = array(
   'meta_query' =>array(
           
        array(
          'key' => 'totalviews',
          'value' => '0',
          'compare' => '>',
          'type' => 'NUMERIC',
          'order' => 'ASC'
       ),

),

'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => '-1',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'category__not_in' => array( 62,63,170,175,176,171,180 ),
'post_type' => 'post' ); This is working but i need to add the other part also is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment:

> it worked without the `array( 'key' => 'picture_url', 'value' =>
>   'none', 'compare' => '!=' )` but I need to include it in the query...
>   is it possible?

Yes, using [named sub-meta queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Named_sub-meta_queries_and_multiple_orderby_arguments) like so:

```
$q_args = [
    // ... other args here ...
    'meta_query' => [
        'picture_url' => [ 'key' => 'picture_url', 'value' => 'none', 'compare' => '!=' ],
        'totalviews'  => [ 'key' => 'totalviews', 'value' => '0', 'compare' => '>=', 'type' => 'NUMERIC' ],
    ],
    'orderby' => 'totalviews', // set this to a key in the above meta queries
    'order'   => 'DESC',
];
```

The `orderby` parameter can also be an array:

```
'orderby' => [
    'totalviews'  => 'DESC', // sort by meta_query key
    'picture_url' => 'ASC',  // sort by meta_query key
    'date'        => 'DESC', // sort by the post date
]
```

And (once again), `orderby` is not a valid argument for an array in the `meta_query` array. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Accepted_Arguments) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works great! I appreciate your help.